# Could not find ContactPicker.apk!

Tags: android

When I am running a simple android application I'm getting "Couldn't find .apk file". Please help me to resolve this problem....

I'm Using

Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.6.1
Build id: M20100909-0800
OS:-Windows 7
Android 2.2

Comment: If you clean your project and rebuild it.. Are there any complaints 
from the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I solved by using JRE system library 1.6 instead of 1.5.  My post cronicles all the other solutions I've seen online, hope it helps.

[apk issue post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778113/android-eclipse-could-not-find-apk)